# Asynchronous queries -- What if another client has a conflicting request?

Tags: database, node.js, asynchronous, race-condition

I didn't know how to word this scenario in the title properly, so I apologize.

More specifically, this is a question I have regarding the asynchronous nature of Node.js (I'm still used to PHP).

Let's say a user is trying to register for an account and, prior to inserting the user, the system checks the database to make sure that his username is unique.

```
var checkUsernameAvailability = function (username, done) {
    someDBImplementation.query('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username = ' + username, function (result) {
        done(!!result);
    });
};

var insertUser = function (username, password) {
    checkUsernameAvailability(username, function (is_available) {
        if (is_available) {
            someDBImplementation.query('INSERT INTO users (...) ...');
        } else {
            // tell the user to pick a unique username
        }
    });
};
```

Let's say two users enter the username `john` at roughly the same time, while `john` is currently not in the database.

The first call to `checkUsernameAvailability` returns that the username is indeed available, so the `INSERT` operation begins.

However, the second call to `checkUsernameAvailability` is faster than the `INSERT` operation, therefore the second user also passes the availability test and the `INSERT` operation starts.

Whichever `INSERT` finishes first (presumably the first user's), by the time the second operation gets executed, it will throw some database error.

I know this is a poor example -- most database systems have a unique constraint built into them to check and handle at the time the operation is run. Still, is there a system in place to maintain the order in which queries are executed? Can I maintain that, if two separate clients make calls to a server, that the second `SELECT` query will wait until the first `INSERT` query is done?

Comment: A much simpler example actually is inventory on a product. What if two people click Buy Now at roughly the same time? First query checks if product has stock (1 item left) and second does an update query to reduce the count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is. Even if there were, you may want to eventually run multiple instances of node on the same server to take advantage of multiple CPU cores, or expand to multiple application servers behind a load balancer. The database would be the one central place that could properly do this uniqueness check.